# NaN error - Dealing with strings and integers

Tags: javascript, html, nan

Making my own version of cookie clicker for the lols at school, having some problems;

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Patrick Clicker</title>
        <script>
            var patricks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("patrickcount"));
            function increment(n) {
                localStorage.setItem("patrickcount", patricks + n);
                document.getElementById("patrickcounter").innerHTML = "Patricks: " + patricks;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="patrick.jpg" onclick="increment(1)">
        <p id="patrickcounter">
            Patricks: 0
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click my face, it says "Patricks: NaN"
I know what NaN means, but I don't know why the error is being caused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work initially because you don't have a value at first in `localStorage`.

You can do this :

```
var patricks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("patrickcount"))||0;
```

Do you intentionally display the value *before* increment ? If that's not your intent, change your function to

```
function increment(n) {
    patricks += n;
    localStorage.setItem("patrickcount", patricks);
    document.getElementById("patrickcounter").innerHTML = "Patricks: " + patricks;
}
```

If you want the page to show the right value right before you click, add this at the end of the body :

```
<script>increment(0)</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well c: The only problem is, when I reload the webpage it says "0", and then it goes back to the order it was before. Is there a method for when the browser loads the page so I can set the correct values? Also, I'm new to html, but I've done a lot of java.

Comment: Nevermind, I read your edit. Thanks, you've been a big help :)